# COMException: Item Default not found in the Presentations collection

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

The task at hand doesn't seem too complex but the implementation is a differnet story. I have a web interface which is used to upload a .pptx file which is them manipulated and eventually moved to a server separate from the web server where the app is hosted. In addidion, I also need to change the file from .pptx to .ppsx.

I've tried to rename the file using a File.Copy method where I gave a different name on the destination end but that seemd to corrupt the file and wasn't able to open it.

Trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop throws the aforementoined error. Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

Here is my code.

Thanks.

```
string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(tempSavePath, fileName);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = null;
foreach (string f in txtList)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(tempSavePath, fileName),Path.Combine(remoteShareSLEBBPortal, fileName));                        
        FileInfo _fileInfo = new FileInfo(@tempSavePath + fileName);
        Process.Start(@tempSavePath + fileName);
        var presCol = app.Presentations;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        pptPresentation = presCol[@tempSavePath + fileName];
        pptPresentation = app.Presentations.Open(@tempSavePath + fileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    }
    catch (IOException copyError)
    {
        WriteException(copyError, "File Coppying");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd bet the manipulation is what is corrupting the file, not the `File.Copy`

Comment: What line is the exception on?

Comment: Changing the extension from PPTX to PPSX doesn't actually corrupt the file, but it *will* cause PowerPoint to refuse to open it.  You used to be able to do this with PPT --> PPS but the new file formats don't permit it.

Comment: @D Stanley: There is no exception, MS Office just can't open the file, as Steve R. pointed out.

Comment: @Steve R. Yes it is clear to me that copying won't work. Do you have a solution or do you know if what I'm trying to do is within the scope of MS Office or?

Comment: You'd need to have PPT open the file, then invoke SaveCopyAs to save a copy of the file as a PPSX.